# element.addEventListener calls function before event?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this question seems a little stupid, I am very new to JavaScript.
Firstly here is my code:

```
        function toggleClass(fElement, fClass = ""){
        if (fElement.getAttribute("class") == fClass){
            fElement.removeAttribute("class");
        }else{
            fElement.setAttribute("class", fClass);
        }
    }

    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var sidebar = document.getElementById("sideBar");

    button.addEventListener("click", toggleClass(sidebar, "closed"));
```

I am trying to toggle a class on click. I am aware that the .onClick event can be used, however, I'm one of those who MUST solve a problem.

I am unsure about what is wrong with this code, as I have researched syntax, and this seems to be correct (I believe). Despite this, as soon as the webpage loads, the closed class is already added to the sidebar element, and clicking the button does not toggle the class attribute.

Help is greatly appreciated...
PS: (if this is a duplicate question please link me to the question)
Thanks!

Comment: because you are calling it, not assigning it

Comment: It should just be simply the name of the function, no parameters or `()`. If you need to pass it parameters, make it an anonymous function.

Comment: chnage button.addEventListener("click", function(sidebar) {toggleClass(sidebar, "closed")}); can solve this.